# How do I make these GTK buttons that are drawn together in a group?

Tags: gtk3

GTK has a way to draw a group of buttons together so they look like one big button with a divider between them, rather than buttons that are drawn apart. It's useful for drawing buttons together that have a similar function.

Here's an example from the GTK inspector, where they appear to be specifically toggle buttons where only one can be selected:

[image]

Another example, from Glade, where each button represents a category of widgets and opens a menu:

[image]

What is this style of buttons called, and how do I make them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GTK Inspector example shows [GtkStackSwitcher](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStackSwitcher.html), a special widget used to control the [GtkStack](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html) (for page switching).

Generally, to achieve this visual effect for a group of buttons, [GtkButtonBox](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButtonBox) is used with the layout style set to GTK_BUTTONBOX_EXPAND.

> Buttons expand to fill the box. This entails giving buttons a "linked" appearance, making button sizes homogeneous, and setting spacing to 0

You can also manually add a "linked" style to any container with buttons:

```
GtkStyleContext *context;
...
context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(button_box);
gtk_style_context_add_class(context, GTK_STYLE_CLASS_LINKED);
```

[HowDoI/Buttons](https://developer-old.gnome.org/Buttons/#Linked_buttons) (paragraph "Linked buttons")